# Cannot post query a webserver using httplib and urlib in python

Tags: python

I am trying to post query to a [webserver](http://www.imtech.res.in/raghava/antibp/submit.html), but it isn't working.

```
import httplib, urllib
import socket
params = urllib.urlencode({'seqname':"GICACRRRFCPNSERFSGYCRVNGARYVRCCSRR", 'format':"nformat", 'terminus':"1", 'method':"1", 'svm_th':"0", 'type': "Submit"})
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/html"}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.imtech.res.in")
conn.request("POST", "/cgibin/antibp/antibp1.pl", params, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
data = response.read()
print data
conn.close()
```

Comment: Please give more information

Answer (score 0):

```
import httplib, urllib
import socket
params = """-----------------------------297992507016600\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="seqname"\r\n\r\n\r\n-----------------------------297992507016600\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="seq"\r\n\r\nGICACRRRFCPNSERFSGYCRVNGARYVRCCSRR\r\n-----------------------------297992507016600\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename=""\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n\r\n-----------------------------297992507016600\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="format"\r\n\r\nnformat\r\n-----------------------------297992507016600\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="terminus"\r\n\r\n1\r\n-----------------------------297992507016600\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="method"\r\n\r\n1\r\n-----------------------------297992507016600\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="svm_th"\r\n\r\n0\r\n-----------------------------297992507016600\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="ann_th"\r\n\r\n0.6\r\n-----------------------------297992507016600\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="qm_th"\r\n\r\n-0.2\r\n-----------------------------297992507016600--\r\n"""


headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
           "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
           "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------297992507016600", "Referer": "http://www.imtech.res.in/raghava/antibp/submit.html",
           "Content-Length": str(len(params))}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.imtech.res.in")
conn.request("POST", "/cgibin/antibp/antibp1.pl", params, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
data = response.read()
print data
conn.close()
```

This WORKS. The thing I noticed this far is that the number (297992507016600 in this case) must be the same in the header Content-Type as in the params.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This works, I don't know what that website has done to the form. But this is how my browser sent the info. You can run the code and get the output you get in a browser.